# Generic lambdas not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I have the following code

```
public interface PredicateGeneric<T,Z>{
    boolean compare(T t, Z z);
}
```

then

```
PredicateGeneric<Integer,Integer> p= (Integer i, Integer j) -> i>=j;
```

and finally

```
public static <T,Z> T getInt(Integer a, Integer b, PredicateGeneric<T,Z> p){
    if(p.compare(a,b)==true){
        return a;
    }else{
        return b;
    }
}
```

the method is called by

```
System.out.println(getInt(4,5,p));
```

in my main method.

I get the following message in Eclipse:
"The method compare(T,Z) in the type PredicateGeneric is not applicable for the arguments (Integer, Integer)"

I've had my troubles with generics in the past, so it doesn't surprise me that I've made a mistake, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Did you mean `p.compare(a,b)...`? Why is `getInt` generic?

Comment: yes, I meant p.compare(a,b). thanks

ok. Thanks for your second question ("Why is getInt generic?")
The method is only called getInt. and I used it to experiment on lambda expressions. You raise a perfect question and the method being generic is really not very sensible. Fixed it by adding/replacing the parameters with generic ones and now it works as I had it in mind

Comment: *Never* write `==true` anywhere. Since the left hand side of such a comparison must be a `boolean` expression, just use that `boolean` expression without distracting curlicues, i.e. `if(p.compare(a,b)) …`. Though, in this case `return p.compare(a,b)? a: b;` is enough to express your intent anyway. And mind that there is already [`BiPredicate<T,U>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/function/BiPredicate.html) doing exactly what your `PredicateGeneric<T,Z>` is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change type declaration to:

```
public static <T,Z> T getInt(T a, Z b, PredicateGeneric<T,Z> p){
    if(p.compare(a,b)==true){
        return a;
    }else{
        return b;
    }
}
```

but now you cannot return a or b because their types don't match the declaration. You can either declare this method with both a and b and return value with the same type or think about different return value.

Comment: Of course, you can enforce both types to be the same, e.g. `<T> T getInt(T a, T b, PredicateGeneric<T,T> p)` or you focus on int values, as the method name suggests, `Integer getInt(Integer a, Integer b, PredicateGeneric<Integer,Integer> p)`